# Device font style theme prevent TextView Typeface to change the font on huawei device

Tags: android, android-fonts, android-typeface

I'm trying to change the font of my Text View Using a typeface like this

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fontName.ttf"));
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
textView.setTypeface(tf);
```

but  Huawei device has a font style customing that if you change the font there it will change the entire device font including my textView as well
How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `fontFamily` or `typeface` attributes in xml, remove theme. Also you can use  [Calligraphy](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy) project that enables actually setting custom font directly from a layout xml.